# How can i get the QR code coordinates in ZXing? (unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, zxing

I would like to make a QR scanner in unity.
I found only the ZXing [library](https://github.com/nenuadrian/qr-code-unity-3d-read-generate)., it detects the QR code but I did not find any way to query the position coordinates. 
I tried the ResultPoints method, but it always returns an empty array. 
Someone have any idea how it's possible?

DLL methods
[image: DLL methods]

Comment: Please don't add code as image! Instead copy and paste your code as text into your question and mark it as code using the `{ }` button.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not my code. Its a screenshot about .NET Reflector, It shows what contain the dll. I can not copy the lines.